# Fill array dynamically PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to fill an array with the links that I get from this foreach. How can I do that?

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
       echo $link->href; //output: link1.html link2.html link3.html......
}
```

Comment: you just have to push your links in blank array

Comment: you can use array_push like all of the other answers here suggest, but I'd recommend using array_map instead -- it's much simpler. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's simple, Try this :-**

```
$dataArray = array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
       $dataArray[] = $link->href; 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dataArray);
 echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```
$links = array_map(function($v){return $v->href;}, $html->find('a'));
```

Comment: + this is a better approach ... any one can loop :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is the best way:

```
$links = array_map(function($link) { return $link->href; }, $html->find('a'));
```

It takes everything in the given array (in this case, `$html->find('a')`) and returns a new array based on a map using the function you give it (in this case, `function($link) { return $link->href; }`). It applies that function to each element in the given array to create each element in the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

With `array_push`. See [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```php
<?php
$stack = array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
   array_push($stack, $link->href); 
}
print_r($stack);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside the loop:
$links[]=$link->href;

Answer (score 0):

```
$hrefs=array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
       $hrefs[]= $link->href; //output: link1.html link2.html link3.html......
}
```

That should do it.